# PHP create a new <ul> after every fifth element in a while loop

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop

Hello I'm trying to output a MySQL query result as a list so that after every fifth line I would like to create a new list.
I did it the same way it was suggested before to a similar question of mine and it separates the results after the fifth line but in every new list the first element is the same as the last in the previous list.

I used this code:

```
/*there is a mysqli query before this*/
$i = 0;
$count = $res->num_rows;
echo '<ul>';
while($obj = $res->fetch_object()){
    $i++;
    $exturl = $obj->link;
    $extname = utf8_encode($obj->title);
    echo '<li><a class="URL" title="'.$extname.'" href="'.$exturl.'" target="_blank">'.$extname.'</a></li>';
    if($i % 5 == 0 && $i < $count){
        echo '</ul><ul><li><a class="URL" title="'.$extname.'" href="'.$exturl.'" target="_blank">'.$extname.'</a></li>';
    }
}
echo '</ul>';
```

And the question is, how can I avoid the duplications?

Comment: Duplications of what exactly?

Comment: `i % 5 == 1` will be true on the 2nd row, when `i` is 1.

Comment: Upps sorry it was a type error I will correct that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whats the point of appending the last li in the conditional?

```
while($obj = $res->fetch_object()){
    $i++;
    $exturl = $obj->link;
    $extname = utf8_encode($obj->title);
    echo '<li><a class="URL" title="'.$extname.'" href="'.$exturl.'" target="_blank">'.$extname.'</a></li>';
    if($i % 5 == 0 && $i > 0 && $i < $count){
        echo '</ul><ul>';
    }
}
```

Since you already echoed it out above the if $i % 5 statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was so distracted by another problem I couldn't see the obvious :)

Answer (score 2):

The solution (depending on how many rows are returned) may be to [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) your results before rendering the lists, resulting in a simple form of pagination.

```
$results = array();

while ($obj = $res->fetch_object()) {
  $results[]= $obj;
}

// Break results into sub-lists of 5 items
$lists = array_chunk($results, 5);

foreach ($lists as $list) {
  echo "<ul>"
  foreach ($list as $obj) {
    $exturl = $obj->link;
    $extname = utf8_encode($obj->title);
    echo '<li><a class="URL" title="',$extname,'" href="', $exturl, '"  target="_blank">', $extname, '</a></li>';
  }
  echo "</ul>"
}
```

This requires you to load your entire result set into memory, but it is a much clearer solution than attempting to conditional close and reopen lists from within a single loop.

Comment: Personally I think this is a much cleaner solution than using mod conditionals

Answer (score 0):

```
$args=array('orderby' => 'title','order' => 'ASC','posts_per_page'=>-1 ,'post_type'=>'Product');
$loop = new WP_Query($args);'
$counter = 1;
$reccounter=1;
$total_items = count($loop);
$ColCounter=($loop->post_count)/3;
if(!empty($loop)){ 
print '<ul style="float:left;list-style:none;" class="productList">';
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
$reccounter++;
$this_char=strtoupper(substr($loop->post->post_title,0,1));                         
if ($this_char != $last_char) { $last_char = $this_char;
$counter++;
echo '<h2 class="productTitle">'.$last_char.'</h2>';
} 
if( $ColCounter<=$reccounter){echo "</ul><ul style='float:left;list-style:none;' class='productList'>";
$reccounter=1;
}   
echo"<li class='productListpad'><a href=".get_permalink($loop->post->ID).   "title=".esc_attr($loop->post->post_title ? $loop->post->post_title :        $loop->post->ID).">".esc_attr($loop->post->post_title ? $loop->post->post_title : $loop->post->ID)."</a></li>";
endwhile; echo"</ul>";
}wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: If you want to display your products alphabetical group use this code and insert it into your php section.It's working for me. For Example see output of this code is click here http://www.levvongroup.com/products/

Answer (score -1):

the solution is to move the if statement in your loop:

Change to this:

```
while($obj = $res->fetch_object()){
$i++;
$exturl = $obj->link;
$extname = utf8_encode($obj->title);
    if($i % 5 == 0 && $i < $count){
        echo '</ul><ul><li><a class="URL" title="'.$extname.'" href="'.$exturl.'" target="_blank">'.$extname.'</a></li>';
} else { 
echo '<li><a class="URL" title="'.$extname.'" href="'.$exturl.'" target="_blank">'.$extname.'</a></li>'; 
}
}
```

Comment: The if statement is already inside the loop... Your code is also full of syntax errors, and will print a leading `</ul>` resulting in broken markup. You're also duplicating *most* of the code. If both branches of your `if` do the *same thing*, you can move that thing outside the if statement. Everything after inside the `<li>...</li>` belongs outside the if statement.

Comment: I didn't proof read, but this is the problem.  The if inside of the loop is in the wrong place.  The duplicate is occurring because on the 5th iteration the <li> is being created and then a second <li> is also being created since the if statement returns true.

Comment: You *should* proof read. This site is meant to serve as a reference, posting broken code which can't even run due to syntax errors doesn't help anybody.

Comment: the duplication is occurring because of the placement of the if statement.  period.  I am not here to clean up this persons code.

Comment: No, not better. You're still outputting a leading `<ul></ul>` which is invalid markup.

Comment: THAT WAS INCORRECT, that would have never printed the LI item.

Comment: Yes it would. Immediately after the `if` block. It would have printed the `<li>` each time through the loop. You do not *need* an `else` for every `if`, that isn't how if/else works. Our code was *exactly identical* in its execution, except mine was readable where as your is an ungodly mess of broken indentation.